# jQuery Ajax Drop Down

Tags: jquery

I have a drop down that when clicked makes an ajax request to update the drop down with the latest stock levels.

When I click the drop down the request is made and the drop down gets updated and drops down with the latest data. Problem is when a user selects an option the Click ajax request is made again stoping an option from being selected.

I did try unBinding the Click function which did work but I could'nt then re bind the click in case a user wanted to change what they selected.

**DropDown**

```
<select name="Qty" id="88" class="ProQty">
   <option value="0">Qty</option>
   ...
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
//Update Qty Levels Automatically
$(function QtyCheck() {
    $("select.ProQty").click(function() {
        var ProductID = $(this).attr('id');

        var Startdd = $("#Startdd").val();
        var Startmm = $("#Startmm").val();
        var Startyy = $("#Startyy").val();
        var StartHours = $("#StartHours").val();
        var StartMinutes = $("#StartMinutes").val();
        var Enddd = $("#Enddd").val();
        var Endmm = $("#Endmm").val();
        var Endyy = $("#Endyy").val();
        var EndHours = $("#EndHours").val();
        var EndMinutes = $("#EndMinutes").val();

        var dataString =  'Startdd=' + Startdd + '& Startmm=' + Startmm + '& Startyy=' + Startyy + '& StartHours=' + StartHours + '& StartMinutes=' + StartMinutes + '& Enddd=' + Enddd + '& Endmm=' + Endmm + '& Endyy=' + Endyy + '& EndHours=' + EndHours + '& EndMinutes=' + EndMinutes;

        $("#" + ProductID).empty();
            //$("#" + ProductID).empty().unbind();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./ajax/QtyCheck.asp?ID=" + ProductID,
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                        //setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#" + ProductID).append(html);
                        //},600);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        //setTimeout(function() {
                            $("#" + ProductID).append(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
                        //},600);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple boolean variable...

```
$(function QtyCheck() { 
  var loaded = false;    
  $("select.ProQty").click(function() { 
    if(loaded) return;
    loaded = true;
    // rest of your code
  });
});
```

You can reset it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding you, it sounds like this is just an event bubbling issue.  Try adding:

```
$('option').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I not sure what you mean though?

Answer (score 0):

Event bubbling: the click event you have on `$('select.ProQty')` also affects the element's children.  This is why the ajax request is sent again when the user clicks an `<option>`.  The click on an option "bubbles up" to `$('select.ProQty').click()`

If you want to stop this bubbling up from happening and the ajax request from being re-sent, you need to stop event propagation.  The following code block will accomplish this.

```
$('option').click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
}
```

Comment: I cant get the stopPropagation to work. Where would I need to add that to my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
Jquery ajax drop down testajax
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Multiple Select Boxes</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loader').hide();
            $('#type').change(function(){
                $('#make').fadeOut();
                $('#loader').show();

                $.post("ajax_make.php", {
                    type: $('#type').val()
                }, function(response){
                    setTimeout("finishAjax('make', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
                });
                return false;
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btn-add').click(function(){
                $('#select-from option:selected').each( function() {
                    $.post("ajax_add_item.php", {
                        product_id: $(this).val(),
                        type: $('#type').val()
                    },function(response){
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    });
                    $('#select-to').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            });
            $('#btn-remove').click(function(){
                $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
                    $.post("ajax_remove_item.php", {
                        product_id: $(this).val(),
                        type: $('#type').val(),
                        removeItem: $(this).text()
                    },function(response){
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    });

                    $('#select-from').append("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
            $('#btn-up').bind('click', function() {
                $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
                    var newPos = $('#select-to option').index(this) - 1;
                    if (newPos > -1) {
                        $('#select-to option').eq(newPos).before("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"' selected='selected'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
            });
            $('#btn-down').bind('click', function() {
                var countOptions = $('#select-to option').size();
                $('#select-to option:selected').each( function() {
                    var newPos = $('#select-to option').index(this) + 1;
                    if (newPos < countOptions) {
                        $('#select-to option').eq(newPos).after("<option value='"+$(this).val()+"' selected='selected'>"+$(this).text()+"</option>");
                        $(this).remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        });  


        function finishAjax(id, response){
         $('#loader').hide();
         $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
         $('#'+id).fadeIn();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="loader"><strong>Loading...</strong></div>
    <fieldset>
        <form name="theform" id="form" method="POST" action="search.php">
                <div style="width:500px;" align="center">
                    <label for="type">Websites:</label>
                    <select id="type" name="type">
                        <?php
                            include('class_dbcon.php');
                            $connect = new doConnect();

                            $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM website ORDER BY website_id ASC");
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
                            {   
                                $intWebsiteId = $row['website_id'];
                                echo '<option value="'.$row['website_id'].'">'.$row['website_name'].'</option>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <br><br>
                <label for="make">Product:</label>
                    <select id="make" name="make">
                        <option value="">-- Select Product --</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div style="width:500px;" align="center">
                    <select name="selectfrom" id="select-from" multiple size="5">
                        <?php
                        if(!empty($intWebsiteId)) {
                            $pna = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p.product_id NOT IN ( SELECT pa.product_id FROM product_associate pa WHERE pa.team_id = ". $intWebsiteId. ")");
                        } else {
                            $pna = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products p WHERE p.product_id NOT IN (SELECT pa.product_id FROM product_associate pa WHERE pa.team_id = 1)");
                        }

                        while($rowPna = mysql_fetch_assoc($pna))
                        {
                            $intWebsiteId = $row['website_id'];
                            echo '<option value="'.$rowPna['product_id'].'">'.$rowPna['product_name'].'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>

                    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-up"><img src="http://localhost:8080/website/IMG/Up-Arrow.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="25" height="20"></a>
                    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-down"><img src="http://localhost:8080/website/IMG/arrow-down.jpg" alt="Pulpit rock" width="25" height="20"></a>
                    <select name="selectto" id="select-to" multiple size="5">
                        <?php

                            if(!empty($intWebsiteId)) {
                                $ipa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products p INNER JOIN product_associate pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id AND pa.team_id =". $intWebsiteId );
                            } else {
                                $ipa = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products p INNER JOIN product_associate pa ON p.product_id = pa.product_id AND pa.team_id =1");
                            }
                            while($rowIpa = mysql_fetch_assoc($ipa))
                            {
                                echo '<option value="'.$rowIpa['product_id'].'">'.$rowIpa['product_name'].'</option>';
                            }

                            $connect->disc();
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <br><br>
                    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-add">Add &raquo;</a>
                    <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" id="btn-remove">&laquo; Remove</a>
                </div>
            </form>
        </fieldset>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/*

    In this class we instantiate an SQL Connection object. Connection details are assinged to 
    object variabes so that they can be used when connecting to the database. The two main 
    functions are conn() and disc(). They are for connecting and disconnecting to the SQL database.

*/
class doConnect
{
    private $databasehost;
    private $databasename;
    private $databaseusername;
    private $databasepassword;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->setRes();
        $this->conn();
    }

    function setRes()
    {
        $this->databasehost = "localhost";
        $this->databasename = "db_website";
        $this->databaseusername ="root";
        $this->databasepassword = "";
    }

    function conn()
    {
        $con = @mysql_connect($this->databasehost,$this->databaseusername,$this->databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
        @mysql_select_db($this->databasename) or die(mysql_error());

    }

    function disc()
    {
        mysql_close();
    }
}
?>
```